# Unity iOS Build export IL2CPP support

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I got below error while exporting game to iOS in unity 4.6.9

```
IL2CPP error for method 'System.String com.shephertz.app42.paas.sdk.csharp.connection.RESTConnectorAsync::ExecuteGet(System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String>,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String>)' in assembly '/Volumes/Development/Project/Top Best Games/52.KingOfRacing2/Source/Source code King 2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/App42_Unity3D_SDK_3.2.dll'
Additional information: Build a development build for more information. An instruction cannot end both a catch and a finally block!
```

[image]

Here is player settings

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue..already googled and none of solution worked...how to solve ?

Comment: 4.6 is really old. I think it's time to upgrade your Unity version. That should remove your error.

Comment: Game exported with 4.6.9  works well in latest iOS also. Even apple approve.